# How to pass the button value into an onclick event?

Tags: c#, html, pagination, parameter-passing, blazor-server-side

I have a for loop which will work out the number of buttons needed to display and then I wanted to pass in that `i` value to the method. However regardless of which button I press it is saying that `i` is 6 and is crashing. How do I get the specific buttons `i` value?

```
    @for (int i = 1; i < maxPage + 1; i++)
{
    <button value="@i" @onclick="@(e => dosomething(this.value))">@i</button>
}


@code {
    int maxPage = 5;
 
    private void dosomething(int val)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(val);
    }

   
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
@for(var i=0; i<5; i++) {
     var index = i;
     <button @onclick="@(e => click(index, 5 * index))">Button @i</button>
 } 


@code {
     private void click(int a, int b) {
         Console.WriteLine(a + b);
     }
 }
```

the variable index holds the value of i for each button so that they don't change and each button has its own value